# At what XM level does your scanner get disabled?

Tags: ingress

Some action can (for instance attacking an enemy portal) drop your XM level below zero.

At some point your tactical scanner will be disabled so that you cannot see anything.

**At what XM level your scanner gets disabled?**

Comment: Sounds strange, if your scanner is disabled, how would you grab XM to recharge ?

Comment: You can only collect XM if the scanner is disabled.

Answer (score 4):

Some observations:

**Scanner Disabled** seems to be an actual number threshold. I have got to around 2% XM (as an L6) and been allowed to hack one last portal before it was disabled. This suggests to me that the limit could be 150 XM (2% of 6k = 160 XM, so 150 is a reasonable 'rounded' value that may apply)

**Scanner Re-enabling** is a different threshold, and could be on percentage basis. From L1-L6, it recovers slightly before 10% is filled up ... maybe 9% of total XM?